# How to get regex to ignore URL strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have the following Regexp to create a hash of values by separating a string at a semicolon:

```
Hash["photo:chase jarvis".scan(/(.*)\:(.*)/)] 
// {'photo' => 'chase jarvis'}
```

But I also want to be able to have URL's in the string and recognize it so it maintains the URL part in the value side of the hash i.e:

```
Hash["photo:http://www.chasejarvis.com".scan(/(.*)\:(.*)/)] 
// Results in {'photo:http' => '//www.chasejarvis.com'}
```

I want, of course:

```
Hash["photo:chase jarvis".scan(/ ... /)] 
// {'photo' => 'http://www.chasejarvis.com'}
```

Comment: Don't you mean that you want: 
Hash["photo:http://www.chasejarvis.com".scan(/ ... /)] 
// Results in {'photo' => 'http://www.chasejarvis.com'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to match up to first colon you could change `(.*)\:(.*)` to `([^:]*)\:(.*)`.

Alternatively, you could make it a non-greedy match, but I prefer saying "not colon".

Answer (score 0):

How do figure out a person's family name and first name?

Changing `chasejarvis` to `chase` and `jarvis` might not be possible unless you have a solution for that.

Do you already know everyone's name in your project? Nobody is having the initial of a middle name like `charvisdjarvis` (assuming the name is "Charvis D. Jarvis".)?